# Append content in body after load jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I loaded some content into the html of a page using:

```
$('html').load('mypage.php');
```

Now I want to append something to the body of the new page content. I tried this:

```
$('html').load('mypage.php', function(){
    var the_body = $('body', $(this));
    the_body.append("<h1>BLAHBLAHBLAH</h1>");
});
```

But I don't see BLAHBLAHBLAH on the new page.

Any help please?

Comment: Why are you using ajax to basically do a page transition?

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: No errors in the console

Comment: [I can't reproduce the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/mowg0xq6/2/).

Comment: ok, I wonder why it's not working for me then.....

Comment: Tried this with content of type HTML (not JSON), it does not work

Comment: Can you try when the content is HTML instead of JSON

Comment: [Still seems to work for me](https://jsfiddle.net/mowg0xq6/4/). Can you create a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Wait a minute, I think I know why it's not working. If the javascript is on the same page that I'm loading the other page's content into, then after the content is loaded, I will no longer have it on the page (since I'm loading everything inside the html tag (not body)